# How to handle android tabHost tab with multiple activities within single tab

Tags: android

Could anyone assist me with tabHost?

I want a solid tutorial with demo examples for managing multiple activities under a running tab.

Suppose tab1 is setcontent with some "Activity A". In "Activity A" I want to start some other activities that should pretend to work in the same tab. How do I do that?

i.e how should I define activities that should work within a single tab...

Is there any other way than GroupActivity or ViewFlipper....???

If not specify in detail about GroupActivity...

With Regards,
Arpit

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `ActivityGroup` in order to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to create a customized tab view, so that only one class can be used to show tabs in various activities.