# tab host and multiple activities (UINavigationController equivalent)

Tags: android, android-activity, uinavigationcontroller, android-tabhost

I'm currently porting iOS App to Android

the iOS app uses tabbar + navigation controller (inside each tab) to load multiples Views

I would like to keep the same design on Android, but I'm a bit confused with it

I tried  "startActivityForResult" to load another activity the TabHost is removed

I also tried to replace the view with setContentView, I'm working, but as some tabs requires more than 10 sub screen, the code will be very elegant.

So I'm looking for a solution to load another Activity in the same tab with a UINavigationController like features

Ex: If I have three tabs A, B, C, on tab A I can go to A1 while pressing some button, If I push back button, I would like A to be displayed

Comment: Try to extend [`TabGroupActivity`](http://ericharlow.blogspot.in/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html) instead of `TabActivity`

Comment: You got it? I means, that `TabGroupActivity` is working?

Answer (score 1):

You can go either with **Fragment** or with **ActivityGroup**.

Fragment is the latest solution where as ActivityGroup is deprecated.

You can refer:

- Activity Group => [this](http://www.jtben.com/document/695851), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306689/launching-activities-within-a-tab-in-android), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856795/how-to-handle-android-tabhost-tab-with-multiple-activities-within-single-tab), [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20100816175634/http://blog.henriklarsentoft.com/2010/07/android-tabactivity-nested-activities/)
- Fragment => [this](http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987334/tabs-in-android-using-fragments)

Comment: Looks like fragments are not supported on older android (I have to target 2.3) , and for ActivityGroup , I dont understand the difference btwn this complicated stuff and simply use setContentView(another_view_id)

Comment: with the help of android-support-v4 library you can access fragment in lower version of android.